# How to add some days in a Datetime attribute in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to retrieve a list based on this LINQ query in C#,

```
    var brief = (from i in _context.Detailed
                           orderby i.BriefSubmittedOn descending
                           select i).ToList();
```

This is the View:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.brief)
    {

            <tr>
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.details</td>
                <td>@item.BriefSubmittedOn</td>
            </tr>

    }
```

The query is working fine, but i don't want the list to remain in this view  forever. Instead i want the items of this list should remain for 3 days only after its date of submission.

For instance, if an item is submitted on 5th May 2019, then it should appear in this list till 8th May 2019 but when the date changes to 9th May 2019, then it should disappear from the list.

Note: The submission date of items are stored in BriefSubmittedOn field in this example, which is of type Nullable DateTime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `where` clause to your LINQ query, e.g.:

```
DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);

var brief = (from i in _context.Detailed
                       where i.BriefSubmittedOn > targetDate
                       orderby i.BriefSubmittedOn descending
                       select i).ToList();
```

You may use `Today` instead of `Now` to use strict timestamp at the edge 00:00:00. if you need 23:59:59 you can add `AddTicks(-1)`